# Magnify Part of a 3D Graphic

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, image-processing

I have a 3D Graphic built, and I want to magnify part of it. I would prefer a circle or ring-shape that can be placed anywhere in front of a 3D graphic that would magnify it. Ultimately, I want to make a GIF where it looks like a magnifying glass is moving across my graphic, so I need to be able to specify where the magnification occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork linked topic is about 2D though.

Comment: @Kuba:  The magnification, as described, will be for the *two-dimensional rendering* of the 3D graphic, so this is fundamentally a two-dimensional problem (and previously solved).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork with a gif as the only requirement yes, but what if one wants to first use it interactively with sharing ViewMatrix option etc.  (it is not yet asked )